# How to use a specific DNS server to resolve a specific domain?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns

I would like to cover the following scenario:

- hosts in domain `example.com` are resolved through the DNS `10.1.1.1`
- hosts in domain `example.org` are resolved through the DNS `10.10.10.10`
- all other hosts are resolved via `1.1.1.1`

Is this something which is possible on Windows 10 natively?

I have a bypass today to use Unbound locally on my machine and have it forward the requests depending on the domain. **I would prefer to use a generic solution, built into Windows 10** (if it exists)

Comment: @LinusWaerner: yes, this is the solution (workaround) which I use, mentioned in my question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. (Previous comment deleted). Then I am afraid there is no way to do this, since Windows uses the priority of the DNS resolvers specified, no matter what domain name you're trying to resolve.